# How does Elasticsearch aggregate?

Tags: elasticsearch

This is more of a general question regarding how ES aggregates, with some examples.

From what I know, ES doesn't care about how small you want to divide the range of one field. For example, you can aggregate the same data in days, months, and even years and the performance in time will come out to be roughly the same.

With the same amount of data evenly spread across, say, 100 days, aggregating data for 7 days will take much less time than aggregating from 100 days. Makes sense as the amount of data contained in the 7 days is much smaller.

But let's say, in scenario 1, we have 100 records across 100 days. in scenario 2, we have also 100 records but only 2 days. Would the time it takes to aggregate still come out to be the same, assuming they have the same setting (# of shards, mapping, anything)? What if we have 1 mil records in 100 days and 1 mil records in 2 days. How much of a difference would there be? I'm not asking for exact number since I didn't give much info (and most of them are made up). I'm just asking about how they would compare relatively.

Comment: It's pretty easy to generate data in two different indices to mimic the cases you've described and then issue two aggregation queries and time them. It's a good exercise. Give it a shot and then we can discuss the results you see ;-)

Comment: How do I do that? Create a database and shard like 7 time with 100 records in it, and another one sharding 100 times with 100 records?